# Why does git rebase have merge conflict but git pull do not?

Tags: git

I have a local branch (lb) which was forked from a remote branch (rb). This forked remote is named 'origin'. lb is tracking origin/rb which is under my personal repo. lb has another remote named 'upstream'. upstream/rb is the public branch that I want to contribute to. Currently lb is consistent with origin/rb. Now I want to integrate the changes happened on upstream/rb to lb before push to upstream/rb. When I do `git pull --rebase upstream rb`, I have a merge conflict. When I do `git pull upstream rb`, no conflict occurred. I am sure that upstream/lb did not modify any files I modified in lb. The rebase conflict message shows the conflict is due to one of my local commits, which is strange to me. Can anyone explain why I got the merge conflict during rebase but not during pull? (Hope this makes sense.) Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This is normal enough.  The reason is that `git rebase` works by *copying* commits—potentially very many commits—with *each copy step being implemented as a merge operation*, while `git merge` works by doing a single merge operation.

Let's draw a simple example of a series of commits in a repository, before a `git fetch` followed by either a rebase or merge (i.e., before `git pull`), and then the series of commits that wind up in the repository after the `fetch` step of a `git pull`.  We start with this as our example:

```
           G--H--I   <-- topic (HEAD)
          /
 ...--E--F   <-- main, origin/main
```

The upstream (`origin`) repository from which we're going to `git pull` has added three new commits to *their* `main`, which our repository reflects as our `origin/main`.  So `git fetch origin` results in this:

```
           G--H--I   <-- topic (HEAD)
          /
 ...--E--F   <-- main
          \
           J--K--L   <-- origin/main
```

Our task—which `git pull` will attempt for us, using either `git rebase` or `git merge` at this point—is to *combine* our work, in commits `G-H-I`, with their work in commits `J-K-L`.

(Remember that each commit holds a full snapshot of *all* files, plus metadata.)

If Git uses `git merge`, Git will locate a single best shared commit—which in this case is commit `F`—and then look at our two end-points, commits `I` and `L`.  Git will *diff* the snapshots in `F` and `I` to find out what we did, and also diff the snapshots in `F` and `L` to find out what they did.  Git must then *combine* these diffs:

- for any file *we changed and they didn't*, Git can use our version of that file;
- for any file *they changed and we didn't*, Git can use their version of the file;
- for any file *nobody changed*, Git can use any version of the file (all three are the same); but
- for files both we and they changed, Git must combine our changes, line-by-line, with their changes, line-by-line.

Git will declare a *merge conflict* if our changes don't exactly match their changes for any lines that overlap or abut.  So if we changed only line 17 of `README.txt` and they changed only line 42, we're all good, but if we changed line 17 and they changed line 17 differently, or they changed line 18, we'll get a conflict.

**Note that Git is not looking at commits `G` and `H` at all here.**  Only three snapshots matter: that in the merge base, from which we both started, and that in each branch-tip.  If all goes well, Git does all the combining on its own and makes a new merge commit `M`:

```
           G--H--I
          /       \
 ...--E--F         M   <-- topic (HEAD)
          \       /
           J--K--L   <-- origin/main
```

(our name `main`, if we have not deleted it entirely to get it out of the way, still points to commit `F`; I've just stopped bothering to draw it in to save space and avoid overlapping with the `M` commit).

#### Rebase is much harder

If we use `git rebase`, however, we are telling Git: *We like our commits `G-H-I` except for one thing: they're in the wrong position.  Throw out the old `G-H-I` series in favor of a new and improved series of commits that come *after* commit `L`.*  The final result should look like this:

```
           G--H--I   [abandoned]
          /
 ...--E--F   <-- main
          \
           J--K--L   <-- origin/main
                  \
                   G'-H'-I'  <-- topic (HEAD)
```

To make this happen, Git will use its *detached HEAD* mode for a while, starting here:

```
           G--H--I   <-- topic
          /
 ...--E--F   <-- main
          \
           J--K--L   <-- HEAD, origin/main
```

Git will then run three `git cherry-pick` operations, to copy commits `G` first, then `H`, then `I`, to new-and-improved commits `G'`, `H'`, and `I'`.  If the copying of `G` is successful we get this:

```
           G--H--I   <-- topic
          /
 ...--E--F   <-- main
          \
           J--K--L   <-- origin/main
                  \
                   G'  <-- HEAD
```

(still in detached-HEAD mode, but with the name `HEAD` now selecting copy `G'`) when Git runs `git cherry-pick hash-of-H`.

The cherry-pick operation can be describe this way: *Compare the commit we want to copy to its parent.  Whatever changes that commit makes, make the same changes here, at the current commit.*  That's logical enough—but there is a hitch.  Suppose that between `G` and `H`, we change line 17 of `README.txt` ... but line 17 of `README.txt` is, in commit `L`, at line *20* because commit `L` itself *added* three lines to the *top* of `README.txt`?  (We didn't touch `README.txt` in commit `G` as compared to commit `F` so things went smoothly earlier and Git just took the commit-`L` version of `README.txt`, so what was line 17 is now line 20.)

To make things match up, Git needs to find not only the parent of `H`—i.e., commit `G`—and diff those two, but also to diff that same parent, i.e., commit `G`, against commit `L`.  That gives Git the ability to combine *what we changed* (from `G` to `H`) with *what they changed* (from `G` to `L`).

This is exactly what `git merge` does.  The only thing special about it is that the *merge base* is forced to be commit `G` here, rather than finding a true merge base.  We're copying commit `H` at this point and its parent is `G`, so the fake merge base for this cherry-pick "merge" is commit `G`.

(The other thing that's a little odd is that the `--ours` commit is commit `L`, not commit `H`.  That's because of Git's detached-HEAD mode.  This is Git letting the implementation show through.  Ideally Git would not call these `--ours` and `--theirs` at all, but rather something like `--rebase-so-far` and `--original`, perhaps.  But it doesn't.)

**This means that `git rebase` runs *three separate merge commands*, one for each commit to be copied.**  If we made a change in commit `H` and then *undid it* in commit `I`, the true merge—which compares `F` vs `I` ignoring  the other intermediate commits—would never see it and never complain about it overlapping some change they made.  But by copying the three commits one at a time, we force Git to see each individual change.

Besides this, Git's `git diff` will sometimes synchronize on inappropriate lines, such as simple close-brace lines.  This means it sometimes "sees" changes that we *did not actually make* instead of the changes that we *did* make.  This of course can affect both a true merge and a rebase, but because rebase may be doing *many* merges, we're more likely to *see* this with rebase.  It's not all that common in practice, but if we're rebasing 30 commits, we have 30 chances to hit it, vs merging once giving one chance to hit it.